# How to Insert into DB2 with NativeQuery and get generated ID

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I'm trying to insert a row into DB2 but i can figure out how to get the generated ID.

With this code it's working but i can't get the ID:

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) VALUES (?)";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(1, "MY_VALUE");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

I did some research, and tried to do like this:

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) VALUES (?)";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(1, "MY_VALUE");
    BigDecimal id = (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();
```

But I got this error:

```
[org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-63) [jcc][t4][10103][10941][4.21.29] Method executeQuery cannot be used for update. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1535)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1574)
...
```

What is the correct way to insert using NativeQuery and get the generated ID?

Comment: This is a FAQ.  Use `SELECT .... FROM FINAL TABLE ( INSERT INTO ... )`

Answer (score 0):

You can run comand like
-- You befor build str_sql in here
str_sql = 'INSERT INTO ............';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_sql;